# AWS - Subscribe queue to a SNS across different environments

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

We have 3 environments test, QA and production. Each with it own account.

This is what I am trying to accomplish. when a user uploads a new solr feed to AWS3 I want to send a SNS. 
The queues in test, QA and production are subscribing to the SNS topic.

In this way I can have 3 services running and keeping my solr instances in sync.

It's super easy to setup AWS3 to send a SNS on a created event and also very easy for a SQS to subscribe to a SNS message.

But how do I subscribe to a SNS topic across all environments? / accounts.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your ask correctly, you'd like to subscribe SQS queues in different AWS accounts to one SNS topic. If so, that is totally possible, documentation for which can be found [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToSQS.cross.account.html).